# How do I find matches in two arrays in IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

For some reason I can't figure this out. But basically I want to compare to models and see if they have any matching emails. Here's my attempt, but this doesn't for some reason work at all.

```
>> CardReferral.all.select{|cf|cf.email == CardSignup.all.collect{|cs|cs.email}}
```

Where I can somehow return the object..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
CardReferral.all.map(&:email) & CardSignup.all.map(&:email)
```

from the [rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html)

**array & other_array**
Set Intersection—Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, with no duplicates.

```
[ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]
```

Comment: Oh wow! Maybe I didn't know what I was doing after all. Never heard of that before. Thank you!

Comment: @trip: yeah, there are all sorts of gems like that in Array and Enumerable :)